# Samsung Gear s3 not connected to tizen studio in windows 7 at home

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

My watch (Samsung Galaxy s3) is connecting to Tizen studio (version: 1.0.2) in office network
But the connection is not successful when I am at home with the same PC & same Watch.

- At office or home both the PC & watch are on the same WIFI network
- Nothing is changed
- I am using Windows 7

Can some one please help me !

Comment: Check your Gear S3 IP type setting: static or dynamic. You may try with dynamic and rediscovery of networks.

Comment: Thanks Yasin.. I will try this and let u know the result

Comment: Thanks for the help !! Its working. Basically I stopped and restarted the SDB service.